# Resilience4J Circuit Breaker does not switch back to CLOSED state

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have implemented a circuit breaker for a service that is called once every 5 minutes.

Looking at the below screenshots:

1. Captures when the outage occurred in the service
   [image]
2. Captures when the circuit breaker opens
   [image]
3. All the calls to the service, after the calls that triggered the circuit breaker to OPEN, are going successfully. *(Notice the timeout count = 2 for the third bar from starting)*
   [image]

I have the following circuit breaker configurations:

```
circuit-breaker:
    automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled: ${AMA_AUTOMATIC_TRANSITION_FROM_OPEN_TO_HALF_OPEN_ENABLED:true}
    failure-rate-threshold: ${AMA_FAILURE_RATE_THRESHOLD:40}
    max-wait-duration-in-half-open-state: ${AMA_MAX_WAIT_DURATION_IN_HALF_OPEN_STATE:5s}
    permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: ${AMA_PERMITTED_NUM_OF_CALLS_IN_HALF_OPEN_STATE:10}
    register-health-indicator: ${AMA_REGISTER_HEALTH_INDICATOR:true}
    sliding-window-size: ${AMA_SLIDING_WINDOW_SIZE:5}
    sliding-window-type: ${AMA_SLIDING_WINDOW_TYPE:COUNT_BASED}
    slow-call-duration-threshold: ${AMA_SLOW_CALL_DURATION_THRESHOLD:5s}
    slow-call-rate-threshold: ${AMA_SLOW_CALL_RATE_THRESHOLD:40}
    wait-duration-in-open-state: ${AMA_WAIT_DURATION_IN_OPEN_STATE:5s}
    writable-stack-trace-enabled: ${AMA_WRITABLE_STACK_TRACE_ENABLED:true}
    minimum-number-of-calls: ${AMA_MINIMUM_NUM_OF_CALL:5}
    timeout-duration: ${AMA_TIMEOUT_DURATION:5s}
```

**Firstly,** according to the configuration, at least 5 calls should fail for the circuit breaker to switch to OPEN, but from the graph, we can see that only 2 failures switch it to OPEN which is not correct.
**Secondly,** Why it is still in an OPEN state after 2 hours. It should have switched back to CLOSED by now.

Comment: you are setting failure-rate-threshold to 40 and sliding-window-size to 5, this means the circuit will OPEN when 2 calls fail, not 5. According to your config circuit will go back to the HALF OPEN state after 5s, and it will only go back to the CLOSED state if there is at least 1 successful call in the HALF OPEN state. If the calls fail in HALF OPEN state it will again go back to OPEN state.

Comment: @YogeshwarChaturvedi But if you see from the attached grafana dashboards, we have had many successful calls after that. Why did it not close??

Comment: are you calling the service in an open state or half-open state? btw it is minimum-number-of-calls not sliding-window-size in the above comment

Comment: I am calling the service in the OPEN state. That is what the logs say. Even in this case, if it makes the minimum-number-of-calls successfully, should it not switch back to the CLOSED state? Which configuration, amongst the one specified above, is causing it to malfunction?

Comment: You should call the service in the half-open state, in an open state it will just reject the request. You can read about the configs here - https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#create-and-configure-a-circuitbreaker

Comment: Any luck here? I am facing the same issue. After successful calls, it went to HALF_OPEN state and remains there. It is not going into CLOSED state.

Comment: @PH I tweaked the various circuit breaker configurations and it worked. Mainly check failure-rate-threshold, max-wait-duration-in-half-open-state, permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state configuration

Comment: A little late to the party here. But, I was encountering a similar issue and I THINK I know the problem.
You have the max-wait-duration-in-half-open-state set to 5 seconds, but you said that this service is only called every 5 minutes. So, what is happening is that when the circuit opens, it waits the wait-duration-in-open-state (also 5 seconds), then it switches to HALF_OPEN state. In HALF_OPEN state, it only waits for 5 seconds. If it does not get a successful call, then it opens again. You should probably remove the max-wait-duration-in-half-open-state setting altogether.